# Xenserver: One VM crashed, xe not reacting any more

Tags: xen, xenserver

We are running a xenserver. One VM crashed, the other VMs seem to run normally.

But now we can not restart this VM any more.

Not even `xe-toolstack-restart` is showing any reaction any more.

We do not want to do a hard-reset of the full system. How can we get the control back?

Comment: check this out http://www.jasonsamuel.com/tag/restart-toolstack/

Answer (score 0):

If all of your vms are shutdown gracefully then a hard shutdown of XenServer doesn't really pose any danger

Comment: The problem is exactly this: We want to avoid shutting down the VMs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
/opt/xensource/debug/destroy_domain -domid <UUID of domain>
```

More info at:

http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX131421

It worked for me once.